# How to search or filter in current folder by typing?

Tags: macos, finder

For example, in my current folder, have following files/folders:

```
myimage
myfolder
mytextfile
```

when I type: "tex", it moves the selection highlight to "mytextfile". Is that possible with finder?

The problem is that, I have many files and folders in my project folder, and I sometime can only remember its sub-name. Having this feature would be very useful.

Comment: This is also the function I need. I hope Mac Finder can select files by typing a few strings.

Answer (score 1):

- Select the folder in the parent folder or press <kbd>⌘↑</kbd>
- Type <kbd>⌘F</kbd>
- Click on the name of your folder in Search Options (here `"Documents"`)

  [image]
- Choose `Name` - `contains` in the search criteria

  [image]
- Type in the text field next to the search criteria.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a shortcut for the last 4 steps?

Comment: No, but you could save your settings (the `Save` button on the right of Search Options), then it appears in the side bar. Right-click it and select "Show Search Criteria". If your are prompted later to re-save the settings, clear the text field.

Comment: Can I just make it shows results in current folder only?

Comment: Type **name:tex** in the normal search field (without ⌘F)